# Importing tensorflow takes 1.5GB of RAM in python process on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

Simple program:

```
import tensorflow
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

The python process takes 1.5GB of virtual memory (commit charge, or "Private Bytes" in Process Hacker 2). If I comment out the "import tensorflow" line, the memory usage goes down to 9MB. The actual working set with tensorflow is only 115MB, but the virtual memory usage is still concerning.

I'm spawning a dozen or more worker processes using ProcessPoolExecutor to train many small models in parallel on a 16-core CPU, so the memory usage of python really adds up.

Is there some way to limit the impact of importing tensorflow on RAM?

Is there a different scheme to train many models in parallel using multiple CPU cores that is more efficient?

Is there a chance to use a free threaded python implementation like IronPython with tensorflow to let threads take advantage of multiple cores, and avoid the process overhead?

Comment: I donk think that it is a good idea to run tensorflow in python threads, because tensorflow already runs in multithreaded mode.

Comment: So, train your models sequentially.

Comment: You should know that virtual memory is not the memory a process uses. It is the address space the OS offers to it.

Comment: 1) A single training session only uses 6% of my 16-core CPU. If I run a bunch of them in parallel, I can get a lot more hyperparameter searching done in the same amount of time. This works, it just uses a lot of virtual memory.

Comment: 2) I thought it was clear when I said the "working set is smaller", that I understood how virtual memory works. However, it's still not fun to commit 2.5gigs of virtual memory per instance. I would prefer to run without a swap file, and I can't.